# Non-linear Perturbations of Minkowski Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory, topology

I am reading some of the [following paper](http://slsedp.cedram.org/cedram-bin/article/SLSEDP_2014-2015____A1_0.pdf) on the bounded $L^2$ conjecture in general relativity where it mentions non-linear perturbations of the Minkowski metric in the context of quasilinear wave equations.

Is it possible for any spacetime manifold (at least in principle) to be represented by a non-linear perturbation of flat Minkowski space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative (if I correctly understand the question)  for *topological reasons*: you cannot change the topology of a spacetime simply changing the metric. There is no chance, for instace, to pass this way from Minkowski spacetime (diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$) to Kruskal (diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2$).